# Standardized coefficients logistic Regression R

Tags: r, logistic, beta-distribution

Is there an analogue to the standardized logistic regression coefficients I can get in Stata for R? I know in regression it is simply lm.beta(model). Is there something like this for logistic regression or profit?

Answer (score 2):

Standardization is not a good idea.  It doesn’t work for categorical variables or for continuous variables that have nonlinear effects on Y.  The standard deviation doesn’t work properly when X has an asymmetric distribution.  Find a meaningful range for X and compute differences in predicted Y over that range.  Inter-quartile-range X effects are useful first attempts.  More [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/validate).

Answer (score 0):

Independent of software, for logistic regression, if you mean-zero standardize any covariates using the relationship

$z_{ij}=\frac{x_{ij}-\bar{x}_j}{\sigma_j}$,

then you can recover what the coefficient, $\beta_j$, for variable $\mathbf{x}_j$ would have been, by dividing the coefficient, $\beta_j^*$, from regression based on $\mathbf{z}_j$, with the s.d. of $\mathbf{x}_j$, as in

$\beta_j = \frac{\beta_j^*}{\sigma_j}$